# How Compare and Swap works

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, compare-and-swap

I have read quite some posts that say compare and swap guarantees atomicity, However I am still not able to get how does it. Here is general pseudo code for compare and swap:

```
int CAS(int *ptr,int oldvalue,int newvalue)
{
   int temp = *ptr;
   if(*ptr == oldvalue)
       *ptr = newvalue
   return temp;
}
```

How does this guarantee atomicity? For example, if I am using this to implement a mutex,

```
void lock(int *mutex)
{  
    while(!CAS(mutex, 0 , 1));
}
```

how does this prevent 2 threads from acquiring the mutex at the same time? Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sure: `ptr`, `mutex`, `NULL`...

Comment: It is safer not to implement your own mutex, but use some from the system, like `pthread_mutex_lock`/_unlock from glibc (with interface defined in POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)

Comment: I am not implementing my own mutex. Just wanted to give an example to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 45):

"general pseudo code" is not an actual code of CAS (compare and swap) implementation. Special hardware instructions are used to activate special atomic hardware in the CPU. For example, in x86 the `LOCK CMPXCHG` can be used (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

In gcc, for example, there is `__sync_val_compare_and_swap()` builtin - which implements hardware-specific atomic CAS. There is description of this operation from fresh wonderful book from Paul E. McKenney ([Is Parallel Programming Hard, And, If So, What Can You Do About It?](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html), 2014), section 4.3 "Atomic operations", pages 31-32.

If you want to know more about building higher level synchronization on top of atomic operations and save your system from spinlocks and burning cpu cycles on active spinning, you can read something about `futex` mechanism in Linux. First paper on futexes is [Futexes are tricky](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/futex.pdf) by Ulrich Drepper 2011; the other is LWN article http://lwn.net/Articles/360699/ (and the historic one is [Fuss, Futexes and Furwocks: Fast Userland Locking in Linux](http://www.cis.temple.edu/~giorgio/cis307/readings/futex0.pdf), 2002)

Mutex locks described by Ulrich use only atomic operations for "fast path" (when the mutex is not locked and our thread is the only who wants to lock it), but if the mutex was locked, the thread will go to sleeping using futex(FUTEX_WAIT...) (and it will mark the mutex variable using atomic operation, to inform the unlocking thread about "there are somebody sleeping waiting on this mutex", so unlocker will know that he must wake them using futex(FUTEX_WAKE, ...)

Comment: As I undersand it, CAS also use lock, but on hardware level? So it's not lock-free, it's only lock free on application level, but not hardware level?

Answer (score 6):

How does it prevent two threads from acquiring the lock? Well, once any one thread succeeds, `*mutex` will be `1`, so any other thread's CAS will fail (because it's called with expected value `0`). The lock is released by storing `0` in `*mutex`.

Note that this is an odd use of CAS, since it's essentially *requiring* an ABA-violation. Typically you'd just use a plain atomic exchange:

```
while (exchange(mutex, 1) == 1) { /* spin */ }

// critical section

*mutex = 0;   // atomically
```

Or if you want to be slightly more sophisticated and store information about which thread has the lock, you can do tricks with atomic-fetch-and-add (see for example the Linux kernel spinlock code).

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** implement CAS in C. It's done on a hardware level in assembly.

Comment: You can get CAS from the language itself in C11 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). You can also use https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html with GCC-compatible C compilers. You can also use OpenACC and OpenMP directives in C programs. OpenMP atomics are supported by all major compilers except Apple Clang.