# What is inner structure of the mutex?

Tags: mutex

I understood that I use mutexes but I don't understood how it works. I mean how it works inside.
How does it exclude another threads or processes when it locked, how does it know who is current owner and etc?
Can a someone post a link on good article about it? Just I found only how it works from programmer's viewpoint, not its realization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the platform/language it is implemented differently. I find Go's [implementation](https://golang.org/src/sync/mutex.go) nice to follow (not *easy* to follow, but more or less clear)

**There, a `mutex` is a struct with two fields**, 32 bit integers:

```
type Mutex struct {
    state int32
    sema  uint32
}
```

If the mutex is not already locked, then the operation basically amounts to a **compare and swap** instruction:

```
    // Fast path: grab unlocked mutex.
    if atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&m.state, 0, mutexLocked) {
        if race.Enabled {
            race.Acquire(unsafe.Pointer(m))
        }
        return
    }
```

Compare and swap, from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), is:

> In computer science, compare-and-swap (CAS) is an atomic instruction used in multithreading to achieve synchronization. It compares the contents of a memory location to a given value and, only if they are the same, modifies the contents of that memory location to a new given value.

The function signature looks like this:

```
func CompareAndSwapInt32(addr *int32, old, new int32) (swapped bool)
```

(How does this work, you ask? [How does Compare and Swap work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339466/how-does-compare-and-swap-work))

If the mutex *is not* unlocked, then the `Lock()` method will have to wait (block the thread) until it can successfully **swap** the values at the `Mutex`'s state.

One thing to keep in mind, is that a specific and immutable address in memory is essential for keeping a `Mutex` working, that is, you can't copy a mutex's value and pass it around -- it's/its a pointer to a shared space in memory.

---

There are resources out there for building a lock itself (although I find golangs more or less short implementation good enough)

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-locks.pdf

https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/15-440-s12/applications/ln/lecture6.html

Comment: Thank you very much! It's that I need.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation is platform and language specific.

Wikipedia lists several popular mutex algorithms and hardware solutions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion

Linux goes with futex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futex

Also check previous discussion

[How are mutexes implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485924/how-are-mutexes-implemented)

Comment: Thank you for links! I read Wiki but in Russian... In English it contains much more information)